# Suggestion: tags for users

Tags: feature-request, users

I think it might prove useful to allow users to post tags on other users. The particular situation which drove me to this was one I'm sure we've all encountered: the new user who has posted their homework assignment with no work or effort evidenced in their question (i.e. no source code). These tags might be advisory to other users to make them aware of tendencies on the part of the users so tagged, or they might have some force - i.e. a user tagged with "homework posting" might get a posting ban for X days, or their questions might get a "response ban" for X days - i.e. no answers or comments would be allowed for a while.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange is not a social network. Focus on posts not people.

Your suggested usage seems like it's just bringing attention to users with behaviour you don't like—that doesn't sound [nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).  And the opposite although completely benign still goes against the philosophy of posts over people.

Who would be able to add these tags? Would there need to be any community consensus, or can anyone tag anyone with anything? That would be a mess. Would users have any control over their *own* tags, or are we going to have to put up with (justified) complaints of unfair taggings?

I can't imagine any implementation of this that makes sense.

No.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange wants to minimize interpersonal friction (along with discussions and other distractions from the goal of producing reference material). Allowing random users to moderate individual users' behavior publicly will definitely not serve this.

Keeping public track of past tendencies also undermines the values expressed in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> We don't hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

Instead, ♦ moderators already have the job of impartially and quietly suspending users with a history of low-quality posts, and the question-ban and answer-ban algorithms do most of the work as it is, privately.

Answer (score 6):

The focus of Stack Exchange sites is on the quality of the questions and answers posted.

Anything that focuses on the users that post them is a distraction that I think should not be considered for implementation.